# Find all function(s) $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x)^2+2xf(y)+y^2=f(x+y)^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> Find all function(s) $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x)^2+2xf(y)+y^2=f(x+y)^2$.

**My Solution:**

> \begin{align} &P(x, 0): f(x)^2+2xf(0)=f(x)^2. \\ &\therefore 2xf(0)=0. \Rightarrow f(0)=0. \\ \ \\ &P(0, y): y^2=f(y)^2. \\ \ \\ &\text{Substituting to the original F.E.: } x^2+2xf(y)+y^2=x^2+2xy+y^2. \\ &\therefore f(y)=0 \text{ or } y. \\ &\text{If } f(y)=0: y^2=0, \text{ Contradiction.} \\ &\therefore f(x)=x.  \end{align}

Please answer it if you have a shorter solution.

Comment: What's the problem with your solution?

Comment: I mean, I was just checking if there is simpler solution. I'm just showing my solution and I am just seeing if there is a simpler and greater proof than mine.

Comment: You could add  "for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$". $2xf(0)=0$ only implies $f(0)=0$ when $2x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x=0$, $f(y)^2=y^2$. So $f(x)=\pm x$.

$\forall x,f(x)=x$ is trivial answer.

When $f$ satisfies $\exists x\ne0\text{ s.t. }f(x)=-x$, then $f$ cannot be an answer because $f(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2\ne x^2-2xy+y^2=f(x)^2+2xf(y)+y^2$ for any $y\ne0$.

I don't know that this is a shorter answer, but one thing is clear that there's nothing wrong with your solution.

Comment: You have $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = -x$ for each $x$. How do you conclude that the same choice must be taken for  *all* $x$? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR Oh gosh I missed, and I edit that hole of my answer.

Comment: Check your edit again. It seems that you assume $f(x) = -x$, but then obtain the contradiction from $f(y) = -y$.

Comment: Yes @MartinR. I think this is valid method.

Comment: @coffeemath No I didn't. In third line, I used "When there exists non-zero $x$ satisfies $f(x)=-x$, then contradiction comes."